# MySQL LIKE pattern returns empty results for strings more than 2 characters length

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing an e-commerce website. I added a search and whenever I perform a search, it returns empty results.

In my products table, I have 6 products that contains the word "senator". Whenever I enter senator in the search form, it returns empty results.

I also tried searching for "se" and it returned the 6 items. I don't know where I'm doing it wrong.

In summary, if I search for strings more than 2 in length, it returns empty results.

Here's my code

```php
$q = $_REQUEST[ "q" ];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE '%{$q}%' ORDER BY id DESC";

if( $DB->numRows( $sql ) > 0 ) {
var_dump( $DB->select( $sql ) );
} else {
echo "No results found";
}
```

EDIT:

Here's the "select" and "numRows" methods

```php
class DB {


    private $conn;

    private const HOSTNAME = "localhost";
    private const USERNAME = "root";
    private const PASSWORD = "";
    private const DATABASE = "store";


    //Constructor
    public function __construct() {
        $this->conn = $this->connect();
    }

    //Connect to database
    public function connect() {

        $conn = new mysqli( self::HOSTNAME, self::USERNAME, self::PASSWORD, self::DATABASE );

        //Check connection
        if( mysqli_connect_error() ) {
            $conn_err = "Error: [ <b>" . mysqli_connect_errno() . " </b> ]<br>Unable to connect to DataBase.<br><br>";
            $conn_err .= "Error details: <br><b>" . mysqli_connect_error() . "</b><br>";
            die( $conn_err );
        }
        
        //Set database Charset
        $conn->set_charset( "utf8mb4" );

        return $conn;

    }

    //Select From Database
    public function select( $query, $paramType = "", $paramArray = array() ) {

        if( $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query ) ) {

            if( !empty( $paramType ) && !empty( $paramArray ) ) {

                $this->bindQueryParams( $stmt, $paramType, $paramArray );

            }

            $stmt->execute();

            if( $result = $stmt->get_result() ) {

                if( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {

                    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {

                        $resultset[] = $row;
                    }
                }
            }

            if( !empty( $resultset ) ) {
                return $resultset;
            }
        }
    }


    //Query Database
    public function query( $query, $paramType = "", $paramArray = array() ) {

        if( $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query ) ) {

            if( !empty( $paramType ) && !empty( $paramArray ) ) {

                $this->bindQueryParams( $stmt, $paramType, $paramArray );

            }

            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();

            if( !empty( $stmt->insert_id ) ) {
                return TRUE;
            } else {
                return FALSE;
            }

        }
    }


    //Bind Query Params
    public function bindQueryParams( $stmt, $paramType, $paramArray = array() ) {

        $paramValueReference[] = & $paramType;

        for( $i = 0; $i < count( $paramArray ); $i++ ) {

            $paramValueReference[] = & $paramArray[ $i ];
            
        }

        call_user_func_array( array( $stmt, "bind_param" ), $paramValueReference );
    }


    //Get Number of Rows
    public function numRows( $query, $paramType = "", $paramArray = array() ) {

        if( $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query ) ) {

            if( !empty( $paramType ) && !empty( $paramArray ) ) {
                $this->bindQueryParams( $stmt, $paramType, $paramArray );
            }

            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $rows = $stmt->num_rows;

            return $rows;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add relevant code, Like the $q init.

Comment: Probably not the issue but it looks as though you are using some form of library for your SQL and the logic looks odd.  Looks as though you run the query to check the number of rows and then re-run the query to return the data, you may want to reconsider how you do this.  You should at the same time consider using prepared statements.

Comment: I'm not using a library, I'm created a class to handle the database operations.

Comment: Have you tried debugging and checked the value of $sql with the input value, 'senator'? Is it showing the correct sql script?

Comment: Show this $DB->select() function's code.

Comment: If you attempt the same query with vanilla mysqli code do you get the same result?

Comment: @Rod Talingting, I tried but it still returns empty. I also tried the full text search, it also returns empty

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input.

Comment: @Proffessor, I'm not good at vanilla

Comment: Seems that it's an issue with your database implementation. Please provide your code of how you initialise and process queries within your $db component.

Comment: _"I'm not good at vanilla"_ - If you're not good at vanilla mysqli, how in the world did you then write your DB-class?

Comment: I've edited the post as requested. @professor, I created the class in php

Comment: @Magnus, I'm using prepared statements. Take a look at my DB class

Comment: I just tried your class with a marginally different query ( still using the `like` operator ) to suit my db - it worked OK

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE '%{$q}%' ORDER BY id DESC";
 Print out $sql, and apply that to the database in interactive mode. That way you will know if the problem is that you are asking the wrong question, or that the database is responding incorrectly.

Comment: @professor I've solved the problem. It was from my wamp server. I restarted it and everything worked out fine. Thank you for your time

Comment: _"I'm using prepared statements"_ - You've written a class that has support for binding the parameters, but you're not using it correctly. You're still _wide open_ to SQL injections. Prepared statements without binding the parameters properly are pointless. Your query should be `WHERE name LIKE ? ORDER ...` and then pass `'s'` as second argument and `["%{$q}%"]` as the third argument. Also, instead of calling your `numRows()`, just call your `select()` and use `count()` in the result. Now you're fetching _all_ rows twice, which is unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 2):

I see nothing wrong within your database **numRows()** method except one with your way of passing the query string into it.

I would definitely suggest you to use [***prepared statements***](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

```
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

if (!empty($q)) {
    $db = `database component initialisation...`;

    $term = "%{$q}%";
    $sql = "select * from products where name like ? order by id desc";

    /**
    * Passing query string in addition with param type 's' => string (2nd argument) 
    * and the actual query param for which 
    * the statement should compare against in like clause (3rd argument).
    */
    if ($db->numRows($sql, 's', [$term]) > 0) {
        // processing...
    } else {
        echo "No results found";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am already using prepared statements for my database operations. I've solved the problem already. It was from my wamp server. Restarted the server and everything works fine